# BigQuery practically unsuable

Tags: google-bigquery

BigQuery's browser interface is practically unusable. 
If I run a query and save it as a table (Enable Options) and then immediately run a query on the new table, bigquery always throws "Error: Query cannot refer to the destination table.". I have to refresh the page to avoid this error.

I just ran a bunch of queries like:
1) Used "Enable Option" to create a Total_A_Table:
Select A, "Table1" as Source from Table1

2) Append to Total_A_Table
Select A, "Table2" as Source from Table2

3) Append to Total_A_Table
Select A, "Table3" as Source from Table3

4) Append to Total_A_Table
Select A, "Table4" as Source from Table4

It keeps showing me results from Step 2 on Step 3 & Step 4. To make it work correctly, I have to refresh the page after each query!

Answer (score 1):

Let's try this with a sample query on public data:

```
SELECT DAY(timestamp) day, AVG(data) data
FROM [data-sensing-lab:io_sensor_data.moscone_io13]
WHERE DAY(timestamp)=15
GROUP BY 1
```

Using the web UI https://bigquery.cloud.google.com/ I click on "Enable Options", "Select table", and I pick a new one.

"RUN QUERY" -> Works

If I want to add data to the new table, I have to change one option. Instead of "Write if empty", I'll choose "Append to table". Now I'll run this query:

```
SELECT DAY(timestamp) day, AVG(data) data
FROM [data-sensing-lab:io_sensor_data.moscone_io13]
WHERE DAY(timestamp)=16
GROUP BY 1
```

And a third query, just to be sure:

```
SELECT DAY(timestamp) day, AVG(data) data
FROM [data-sensing-lab:io_sensor_data.moscone_io13]
WHERE DAY(timestamp)=14
GROUP BY 1
```

Now I want to see everything on my new table. How about:

```
SELECT day, data
FROM [my_dataset.my_new_table]
```

Before this query will work, I need to click on "Disable options", as I don't want the results of this query to get appended to its table. Click, and run:

```
Row day data     
1   16  15597.3806764996     
2   15  15817.908626749544
3   14  15183.43383563708
```

Works for me! If you follow these steps, does it work for you without the need to reload?

Comment: Apologies for the late reply. 
But I'm getting this 
Error: Not Found: Table XXX:XXX:io_sensor_data.moscone_io13

Comment: oops, [data-sensing-lab:io_sensor_data.moscone_io13]

Answer (score 0):

It worked. I was not "Disabling the options" before running the last select query in the example above that was causing my problems.

Since the error said "Error: Query cannot refer to the destination table. " - I could not catch my error easily.

Thank you!